# Where are ContentItem.Parts.Fields values stored?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

Given code like this:

```
IContent part = ....; // some part object like IUser
var fieldValues = part.ContentItem.Parts
   .SelectMany(p => p.Fields)
   .Where(f => f.Name == "some field name");
```

Which table are the field values stored in, or are they stored somewhere else?

I'm using SQL Server as the back-end database for Orchard. I see the fields are defined in table `Settings_ContentPartFieldDefinitionRecord` but I don't know where the actual values are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord

Check out this blog post by the lead developer on Orchard, Sebastien Ros, who talks a little about the database structure. http://sebastienros.com/understanding-orchard-s-database

Comment: Thanks! And on top of that, the data is stored in XML in the `Data` column.